# Mini-css-extract-plugin doesn't bundle my css into one single file with sass

Tags: javascript, css, webpack, sass, mini-css-extract-plugin

When i try to add the sass-loader and run webpack there is multiple chunck .css files in the dist folder instead of just the bundled one named "style.css".

My dist output folder looks like:

```
0.e749007119be51de03e4.js  1.e749007119be51de03e4.js  bundle.e749007119be51de03e4.js
0.style.css                1.style.css
```

I guess it's because of the Mini-css-extract-plugin but i can't figure out how to fix it.

Here is my webpack file:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const { resolve } = require('path');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');

const ROOT = resolve(__dirname);
const SRC = resolve(ROOT, 'src');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',
  entry: {
    bundle: [
      'react-hot-loader/patch',
      'webpack-hot-middleware/client?reload=true',
      resolve(SRC, 'client', 'index.js'),
    ]
  },
  output: {
    path: resolve(ROOT, 'dist', 'client'),
    filename: '[name].[hash].js',
    publicPath: '/'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        use: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        include: resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules', 'react-toolbox'),
        use: [
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          // 'style-loader',
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              modules: true,
              sourceMap: true,
              importLoaders: 1,
              localIdentName: '[name]_[local]_[hash:base64:5]'
            }
          },
          // 'postcss-loader'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: ['style-loader', MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader', 'sass-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        exclude: resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules', 'react-toolbox'),
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpe?g|svg|png|gif)$/,
        use: ['file-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf)$/,
        use: ['file-loader']
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: 'style.css',
    }),
  ]
};
```

Any idea ?

Comment: That is code splitting, why you are bothered by that? It is helping you... big file size harms the user

Comment: There is two problems coming with this way. If i wanna use a plugin like `html-webpack-plugin` the index.html file is not filled with the `<link href="/bundle.css" rel="stylesheet">` anymore. Secondly the normal behavior of MiniCssExtractPlugin shouldn't be to create a file style.css like i precised in the constructor ?

Comment: No, since you have async chunks, it is going to create a style.css for each style that is removed from those async chunks.

Comment: I assure you that if you are using html-webpack-plugin it is going to work. It is just not added there because those css had not came from one of the entry points. THat is why it is not inserted directly into the html. I have a similar project and it works perfectly.

Comment: Well i see, but the thing is that i wanna do SSR in a near future, should i not insert the css too and it's gonna work ?

Comment: If those are not emmited from the entry point, there are going to be loaded dynamically by webpack once those chunks are requested.

Comment: Looks like magical stuff but still gonna try this !

Comment: Seems you're right after searching into the bundle.js file i found this `bundle.js
793:/******/     var href = "" + chunkId + ".style.css";`

Comment: see?? :) the powerfullness of code-splitting!!!

Comment: i'll post this as an answer, on all those questions you made

Comment: Something is broken for me. I have a 0.style.css in my dist folder but it is never loaded when components are loaded asynchronously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> There is two problems coming with this way. If i wanna use a plugin like html-webpack-plugin the index.html file is not filled with the  anymore. Secondly the normal behavior of MiniCssExtractPlugin shouldn't be to create a file style.css like i precised in the constructor ?

No, since you have async chunks, it is going to create a style.css for each style that is removed from those async chunks.

I assure you that if you are using html-webpack-plugin it is going to work. It is just not added there because those css had not came from one of the entry points. THat is why it is not inserted directly into the html. I have a similar project and it works perfectly.

If those are not emmited from the entry point, there are going to be loaded dynamically by webpack once those chunks are requested.

**Big files harms users. Code splitting is always the answer for everything!!**

Comment: Seems to be the right answer, i marked it as the solution meanwhile i test everything !

Answer (score 1):

Check out this piece of code from the documentation

```
module: {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.(sa|sc|c)ss$/,
      use: [
        devMode ? 'style-loader' : MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
        'css-loader',
        'postcss-loader',
        'sass-loader',
      ],
    }
  ]
}
```

if you see carefully you'll see that it's using `style-loader` in dev mode and `MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader` for production. So in production it will generate another file for css.

What you need to do is this:

In your `package.json` file in the script section you need to pass a env variable `devMode` like this

```
"scripts": {
  "webpack": "webpack",
  "start": "npm run webpack -- --env.mode=development"
}
```

Then in your `webpack.config.js` file you need to do this

```
module.exports = (env) => {
  const devMode = env.mode === 'development'
  return {
    mode: env.mode, // will be development
    devtool: ...,
    entry: { ... },
    output: { ... },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.scss$/,
          use: [devMode ? 'style-loader' : MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader', 'sass-loader']
        }          
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

That should be ok, hope it helps.

Comment: Firstly thanks for your quick answer ! I have seen this before too in the documentation, the problem is that even do i'm trying this way with `style-loader` in development mode the scss files aren't outputed in any .css file anymore..

Comment: did you try merging your rules for `css` maybe that's the problem, right now you have a couple of them

Comment: I cannot merge them because i'm using specific configuration with include/excluse for the react-toolbox library.. Gonna still try :)